# Django duplicated SQL queries

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and redis to build a ranking application,items score are stored in a sorted set with the key "ranking:id:item_rank". Django-debug-toolbar says SQL queries have duplicates when i display rankings and its top three items in index page.

**# models.py**

```
class Ranking(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True) 
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ranking = models.ForeignKey(Ranking, related_name='items')
```

**# views.py**

```
def index(request):
    rankings = Ranking.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'rankings': rankings})
```

I create custom template tags to display top three items in index page.

**# templatetags/ranking_tags.py**

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
                      port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
                      db=settings.REDIS_DB)

@register.assignment_tag
def get_top_3(ranking):
    item_rank = r.zrange('ranking:{}:item_rank'.format(ranking.id), 0, 2, desc=True)
    item_ids = [int(id) for id in item_rank]
    items = list(Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids))
    text = ''
    try:
        text = '<p>#1 :' + items[0].title + '</p>'
        text = text + '<p>#2 :' + items[1].title + '</p>'
        text = text + '<p>#3 :' + items[2].title + '</p>'
    except:
        pass
    return text
```

**# index.html**

```
{% for ranking in rankings %}
  <div>
    <h4>{{ ranking.title }}</h4>
  </div>   
  <div>
    {% autoescape off %}
    <div>
      {% get_top_3 ranking %}
    </div>
    {% endautoescape %}
  </div>    
{% endfor %}
```

**# Django Debug Toolbar**

```
1.SELECT "myapp_ranking"."id", "myapp_ranking"."title" FROM "myapp_ranking"
2.SELECT "myapp_item"."id", "myapp_item"."title" FROM "myapp_item" WHERE "myapp_item"."id" IN ('1', '2', '5')
Duplicated 2 times.
3.SELECT "myapp_item"."id", "myapp_item"."title" FROM "myapp_item" WHERE "myapp_item"."id" IN ('8', '10', '7')
Duplicated 2 times.
```

now I have 2 rankings in database, so there're two duplicates. more rankings, more duplicates. How to decrease sql queries? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `list()` on `QuerySet`, it makes Django ORM to evaluate query for each item in a list, then keeps it in memory.

Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)